# Web scraping vs Cloud Storage with AWS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-design, web-scraping, rds

My team has run into a design conflict. We are working on a project that involves scraping historical data from yahoo for all stocks for the last year to run some ML analysis on it. The latency is unbearably slow, not sure if it's the network or the web scraper. I proposed we use AWS RDS to store the data so we can access it quicker. However, a team member said that storing the data in the cloud would not solve our latency issue. I rebutted with the fact that the data will be organized and stored in a way to access the data significantly faster. He came back with something else and this went on. Is it true that a cloud DB won't offer any additional speed compared to a scraper? If so does AWS have a service that allows us to access the data we store faster through another service, almost as if the database was on our own server?

I am not that all familiar with cloud services but I do understand databases pretty well. So please dumb down the AWS stuff if you wish and feel free to point me to any duplicates or links that may help me understand this more.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of good reasons to use RDS as a database, but speeding up your scraping isn't one of them - it likely isn't your bottleneck.

I have written lots of scrapers over the years, and by far the biggest performance boost will be to have a fast network connection between the scraper machine(s) and the host you are scraping, and even then, using a multi-threaded scraper for each scraping machine will give you another HUGE speed improvement.

Most time spent scraping is waiting on the host to return the results to you, not parsing the page and not saving the database to a database.

Answer (score 1):

A MySQL DB on AWS RDS would be the same as the one that you'd install yourself on some machine. So, it isn't going to be different or slower just because it is *in the cloud*.

If you scrape some data and process it only once, then there is no point in introducing a DB in between. But if your scraper is slow and you process scraped data multiple times, then storing it in a DB should improve latencies. That is because the latencies of a DB read will be much lesser than that of scraping (assuming you design your DB schema properly; your hosts are in the same availability zones, or at least regions, as your DB etc.).

For e.g., if scraping a webpage takes ~10s and you process the scraped data twice, it'd take you ~20s if you don't have a DB. If you have a DB which has latencies of ~500ms you'd only take ~11s.